# Websphere Application Server v7 Configurations without restart?

Tags: jms, datasource, websphere-7, restart

Does anyone know of any way to make a datasource configuration change in WAS 7 without a complete restart of the app servers?  I need to change the database URL and would rather not bring down all my app servers to do so.

From what I can gather, these resources are bound at server startup and recycling the server is the only way to recognize the new configuration.  For example, if your driver switched from oci to thin, you may have some connections still in the pool, which could be troublesome.

I am also curious if its possible to change JMS resource information, such as a Queue or Topic JNDI name without a restart.

Please let me know.  It doesn't really seem either of these are possible to change without a restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart the server for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this wsadmin script causes the resources to be reloaded without a restart.  However, my attempts were not really conclusive as I needed to restart the server for the new address to be picked up.

```
wsadmin>set dsh [$AdminControl queryNames process=server1,type=DataSourceCfgHelper,*]
wsadmin>$AdminControl invoke $dsh reload
```

But, as a workaround, when I really need to change something in a datasource and don't want to restart the whole server (you would still have to restart the application), I create a new datasource and then change the resource bindings from the admin console *Enterprise Applications > MyAPP > Resource references*

Answer (score 0):

reaload dont work because:

"public void reload()

```
Reloads resources.xml. This function may be called to bind a new data source after server start. **It does not impact existing data sources**."
```

link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/DataSourceCfgHelper.html